# ScalaTest and Maven: getting started

Tags: testing, scala, maven-2, junit4, scalatest

I have a Maven/Java project I've been working on for years, and I wanted to take [JavaPosse](http://javaposse.com/java-posse-353-roundup-11-scala-adoption)'s advice and start writing my tests in Scala. I've written a few tests following [ScalaTest's JUnit4 quick start](http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_junit_4), and now I want these tests to be executed while running "mvn test". How should I do this? What should I put into my pom.xml to allow the tests in src/test/scala to be run side-by-side my old JUnit4 tests?

Cheers

Nik

PS, yes, I've been Googling, but all I could find on the topic were some pre-v1.0 suggestions that I didn't get working

PPS, bonus question: how can I run these tests one-at-a-time by rightclicking them in Eclipse/STS and say "Debug As... ScalaTest" or something similar where I've so far said "Debug As... JUnit Test"?

PPPS, I expect the answer has changed since [July '09](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093520/is-there-a-scala-unit-test-tool-that-integrates-well-with-maven)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second answer in one of the questions you linked to SHOULD work:
[Is there a Scala unit test tool that integrates well with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093520/is-there-a-scala-unit-test-tool-that-integrates-well-with-maven/1564619#1564619)

You annotate your tests with a junit @RunWith annotation and give it the scalatest http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.0.RC3/#org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

If your Tests also adhere to any naming conventions possibly enforced by Maven, this should work fine.

Note: It doesn't matter what kind of scalatest trait you use. All of them should work. If they don't and Bill Venners doesn't answer to this question, contact him on the ScalaTest mailing list.

Other Note: you can run such test suites in Eclipse using the normal JUnit plugin. But you can't run single tests, since the plugin expects to deduct a method name from the test name, which doesn't work with all types of scalatest tests.

Comment: I was following those lines, but for statements such as "import org.junit.runner.RunWith" I got "error: value junit is not a member of package org". The answer says 'Soon we plan to deploy it "officially" in a Maven repository', so I don't really know what happened there, but I haven't been able to dig up any example project with a pom.xml and a few test classes to have a look at

Comment: That sounds like you don't have JUnit in your classpath. Add it as a (test) dependency and you should be fine

Comment: I couldn't believe it when I realized that. You're very right, I was missing JUnit. I've "always" had it in my class path, but not this time. Thanks for the explanation :-)

Comment: Broken links, out of date answer.