# Is there a Java continuous testing plugin for Maven?

Tags: java, maven, continuous-testing

I'm looking for a plugin that would run in a console continuously to scan a Maven project's test sources directory, and when it detects a change kicks off a test cycle. Something analogous to `mvn scala:cc` or the Scala Build Tool, but for Java. Can anyone point me towards one?

Comment: This might be obvious but, you are aware that there are continuous integration servers with good support for maven, right? e.g. [Jenkins-CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/)

Comment: Yeah, I do. I am looking for something simple out of the box to run in a console alongside a text editor when I don't have access to a full-blown IDE.

Comment: Ok, all clear. You want eclipse's autobuild functionality minus eclipse :)

Comment: That's pretty much it :)

Comment: but jenkins offer a consloe command interface to manipulate it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have personally used sbt even for a java only project just for continuous test feature.

I added a sbt build file to a maven based project and use sbt when developing, but use maven when building the final package, starting embedded jetty etc and this has worked out quite well.

Comment: That's certainly one way to do it, but I'm looking for something that wouldn't require me to introduce sbt.

Comment: It's quite possible that there isn't actually a Maven continuous compilation plugin, so this is the best answer that I received. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've just discovered that the [scala-maven-plugin](http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin/index.html) supports both continuous compilation & testing, as well as cross-compilation (Java + Scala). So it's possible to use it over a pure Java build and get all the continuous build goodness.

Comment: You're a genius, sir! :D It worked. see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4079288/539481

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I have had a need for a solution to this. Having been learning scala and finding about the goodness of sbt ~test, I want to apply it to **Java projects that do not have continuous test**.

Using the scala-maven-plugin that you mentioned, I have created a github seed that **will run Java Junit tests everytime I save a Java source or a Java test**.

Check it out:
https://github.com/ailveen/maven-scala-java-continuous-test

The project is very simple right now (contains only Java files because that is my current need) but in the future I hope to add scala test (or specs2 or scalacheck) so it works with mixed java and scala files.

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly for Maven, but [JUnit Max](http://junitmax.com/) does continuous testing and if you're on Eclipse it might be the tool you would like to check out